# Refused to execute a JavaScript script. Source code of script found within request

Tags: control-panel, javascript, xss

In my control panel, I am getting a bunch of javascript errors, starting with:

Refused to execute a JavaScript script. Source code of script found within request.

I read something about XSS filters and attacks - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547884/refused-to-execute-a-javascript-script-source-code-of-script-found-within-reque/1547887#1547887 - I'm not sure how to debug the problem.[image]

Answer (score 1):

First, start by making sure the jQuery module is installed on the Module page.

---

Next, try disabling EE's XSS sanitizing.

[image]

[image]

---

Then, I'd disable Extensions by adding this to your config.php file or by changing the config to "n" if it already exists in config.php.

> $conf['allow_extensions'] = "n";

This will eliminate code in one of the extensions as part of the problem.

If disabling Extensions eliminates the error, then you know it's one of the installed Extensions and you can start uninstalling them one by one to determine which extensions. Note: When you uninstall an extension you will lose any data/settings associated with it so a backup is in order if you don't want to reset up Extension settings when you reinstall.